# Not able to initialise the JS library on checkout page to utilize it on click of place order

Tags: magento2

I have a library in `JS` at this path in a module.

`magento2\app\code\vendor_name\module_name\view\frontend\web\script.js`

And it is initialised to the header with the following code:

`checkout_index_index.xml`

```
       <script src="Roman_hello::js/view/hello-init.js"/> 
</head>
```

And `require-config.js` file in 
`vendor_name\module_name\view\frontend`

with the following code:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            lazyloadScript:'vendorname_modelname::library/dist/libscript.min.js'
        }
    }
};
```

And on click i call the initialised library to the default.js at this path.

`vendor_name\module_name\view\frontend\web\js\view\payment\default.js`

but as always this gives error `default.js:31`

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: default_var is not defined at
>   default.js:31

below is the default.js file.

```
define(
    [
        'uiComponent',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/renderer-list'
    ],
    function (
        Component,
        rendererList
    ) {
        'use strict';
        rendererList.push(
            {
                type: 'payment',
                component: 'vendor_module/js/view/payment/method-renderer/iostpay-method'
            }
        );
        return Component.extend({});
    }
);
 function log(msg) {

      console.log( msg ) ;
    }
 var transfer;
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async function(event) {
      await new Promise(done => setTimeout(() => done(), 500));

      IWalletJS.enable().then(function(account) {
        if(!account) return;

    const iost = IWalletJS.newIOST(IOST);

        transfer = function() {

          const tx = iost.callABI("token.iost", "transfer", ["iost", account, 'account****', "10", "dapp test memo"]);
          tx.addApprove("iost", "10");

          console.log(tx.getApproveList());
          iost.signAndSend(tx)
            .on('pending', function(txid) {
              log("txid: " + txid);

            })
            .on('success', function(result) {
              log("res: " + JSON.stringify(result));

            })
            .on('failed', function(failed) {
              log("failed: " + JSON.stringify(failed));

            })
        }


      })
    })
```

what thing am I missing?

Comment: can you post `default.js` code.

Comment: `define(
    [
        'uiComponent',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/renderer-list'
    ],
    function (
        Component,
        rendererList
    ) {
        'use strict';
        rendererList.push(
            {
                type: 'iostpay',
                component: 'Iostpay_Iostpaymagento/js/view/payment/method-renderer/iostpay-method'
            }
        );
        return Component.extend({});
    }
);

const iost = IWalletJS.newIOST(IOST);
`

I need this IOST to be initialised. 
Thanks

Comment: is this default.js code? there is no 31 line

Comment: ` const iost = IWalletJS.newIOST(IOST); `

This is the code. I want to initialise the IOST in default.js at this path

` vendor_name\module_name\view\frontend\web\js\view\payment `.

Comment: I have shortened this code, as no more characters were left to comment.

Comment: update code in question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100579/discussion-between-garry-and-rakesh-varma).

Answer (score 1):

adding header from checkout_index_index.xml

```
 <head>
     <link src="Iostpay_Iostpaymagento::js/hello.min.js"/>     
     <link src="Iostpay_Iostpaymagento::js/test_func.js"/>   
 </head>
```

And instead of import function used

```
    require(['abc']);
```

and this initialised the class in the test_func.js file. In the plain HTML page although the import of class was not required, in magento2 importing of the class made things working fine `enter code here`.